# Array Sorting Function - C++

Tags: c++, arrays

intent is to create an array of random numbers, and sort them in ascending order
array is created, but sorting does not work (numbers are printed in random order)
have i incorrectly applied sorting by reference?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

void mySort(long x[])
{
long min(0), temp(0), minPosition(0), i(0), j(0);
min = x[0];


for (j = 0; j < 10; j++)
{


    for (i = j; i < 10; i++)
    {
        if (x[i] < min)
        {
            min  = x[i];
            minPosition = i;
        }
    }


    temp = x[minPosition];
    x[minPosition] = x[j];
    x[j] = temp;

}


}

int main()
{

long *myArray = new long[10];
int i(0);

srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    myArray[i] = rand()%11;
}

mySort(myArray);
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    cout<<'['<<myArray[i]<<']'<<endl;
}
return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

One thing that stands out is that you need to reset `min` and `minPosition` every time your outer loop kicks off. At the moment, things will go badly wrong from the second iteration onwards.

Also, be aware that this (selection sort) is a rather inefficient way to sort a list. It runs in `O(n^2)` time, rather than `O(n log n)`, which is what good sorting algorithms do (Quicksort, Heapsort, Mergesort).

Answer (score 0):

Well if you dont know how to sort ...you can use sort() function as

```
// sort() Example using arrays.
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

const int SIZE = 7;

int main()
{
    int intArray[SIZE] = {5, 3, 32, -1, 1, 104, 53};

    //Now we call the sort function
    sort(intArray, intArray + SIZE);

    cout << "Sorted Array looks like this." << endl;
    for (size_t i = 0; i != SIZE; ++i)
        cout << intArray[i] << " ";

    return 0;
}
```

Found in ~ `#include <algorithm>`

```
Parameter 1 myvector.begin() ~ The first parameter is where you will be putting a iterator(Pointer) to the first element in the range that you want to sort. The sort will include the element that the iterator points to.

Parameter 2 myvector.end() ~ The second parameter is almost like the first but instead of putting a iterator to the first element to sort you will be putting a iterator to the last element. One very important difference is that the search won’t include the element that this iterator points to. It is [First,Last) meaning it includes the first parameter in the sort but it doesn’t include the second parameter in the sort.

Parameter 3 myCompFunction() Optional ~ The third parameter is used to define how you do the search. For example if you have a struct that has 3 different variables in it.
```